# Force the user to type an specific numeric value (Pascal)

Tags: string, pascal, numeric

I'm trying to make a program that reads an binary code, but I can't think of something to end the program if the user type any other number than 0 or 1.
I already tried the "Pos" command, but if the user write like "10012" it would still work fine, but I want it to not work in that particular scenario

EDIT: Posting the code.

```
Program Binario2 ;
var
    bin, size, expo : Integer;
    temp, result : Real;
    binI : String;
Begin

 writeLn('CONVERSOR DE NÚMERO BINÁRIO PARA DECIMAL');
    write('Digite o número que quer converter: ');
    read(bin);

  str(bin, binI);
  size := length(binI);
  expo := 0;

    while size <> 0 do
    begin
    if binI[size] <> '0' then
    begin
      temp := exp(expo * ln(2));
      result := result + temp;
    end;  
    expo := expo + 1;
    size := size - 1;
  end;
  write('O número ', bin, ' em decimal é: ', Round(result));
  ReadLn();
End.
```

Comment: My guess is the code you've written does not work the way you want.

Comment: If you post some example code, there is a better chance someone can help you. for example to figure out why it does accept other things than `0` or `1` in the first place, and then go from that.

Comment: Work with the string, not with the **decimal** number `binI` you get with `Str()`. The value `binI` is useless here. Check char for char: if '0', shift the result. If '1', shift the result and add 1, if anything else, abort the program.

Comment: Thanks Rudy! Got it working now!